# Django Model Form validation doesn't show

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I needed some validation on a Django ModelForm field. So I changed 2 lines in my models.py (*just below*). The validation is blocking as necessary, but I can't find the proper way to display the ValidationError. Maybe there is a cleaner way to do this in the model form ?

**models.py**

```
class Lexicon(models.Model):

    [...]

    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', _('Only alphanumeric characters are allowed'))
    filename = models.CharField(_("Filename"), max_length=40, validators=[alphanumeric])
```

**forms.py**

```
class LexiconForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lexicon
        fields = ['filename', 'language', 'comment', 'alphabet', 'case_sensitive', 'diacritics']
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def new_pls_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LexiconForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('pls_edit')
    else:
        form = LexiconForm()
    return render(request, 'main/new_pls.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

**template.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'new_pls' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

[...]

{% if form.is_bound %}
    {% if form.filename.errors %}
        {% for error in form.filename.errors %}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ error }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.filename.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ form.filename.help_text }}</small>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% render_field form.filename type="text" class+="form-control" id="plsFilename" placeholder=form.filename.label %}
```

Replacing my entire form by `{{ form }}` as @Alasdair suggested is working, so I guess something is wrong with my template rendering.

Comment: Do you see the errors if you display the form with `{{ form }}` instead of rendering the fields manually? Please show `LexiconForm`. Please check the indentation of your view matches your code *exactly*, in particular the `else` block.

Comment: No it doesn't show, even with `{{ form }}`. Edited my question for LexiconForm. Also corrected indent in my post as you suggested.

Comment: What are you entering in the form to test it, and how do you know that the validator is working (e.g. are you printing `form.errors` in the view)?

Comment: Tried with different things like test*, test test, test-test, I think the validator is working beacause I stay on the same page instead of being redirected in case of success. **form._errors** contains "{ErrorDict}<ul class="errorlist"><li>filename<ul class="errorlist"><li>Only alphanumeric characters are allowed</li></ul></li></ul>"

Comment: I don't think the code you've posted explains the problem. If `form.errors` contains the validation error, and your view indentation is exactly the same as your question, then `{{ form }}` in the template should display the errors.

Comment: That doesn't help me a lot :p

Comment: Sure, but we can’t really help unless you can show an example that reproduces the problem, and I don’t think your current question does that :p

Comment: What more would you want me to post haha

Comment: As I said, you need an example that reproduces the problem. Your question has lots of `[...]` where we don’t know what’s going on. The simpler the example, the more likely you are to get help, so don’t include a complicated template if `{{ form }}` shows the same issue.

Comment: I came back at it and I figured I actually forgot to let form.non_field_errors when I tried to replace my form by `{{ form }}`. Now it prints the errors, so what could be wrong with my template ?

Comment: Oh, I understand ! I thought I was only a Model thing. I also thought the mistake would be brought up by form.filename.errors. I already iterate over the list of filename errors to display them if there is any, so the ValidationError isn't one of these ?

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment, it didn't make sense. If `{{ form }}` displays the error, then `form.filename.errors` should display the error as well. Your template is more complicated than it needs to be (e.g. unnecessary `form.is_bound` check), but I can't see anything that explains why the error isn't displayed.

Comment: I replaced my complicated template error rendering by `{{ form.field.errors }}` everytime and the error now prints ! How can I display it in a nicer way in terms of design, maybe using Bootstrap classes ?

Comment: Glad you got it working. Restyling the fields is a completely different question. I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! How can I mark this question as resolved as you didn't post an answer?

Comment: You can add and accept your own answer which shows the changes you made to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simply replaced my error printing by this and the error prints!

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'new_pls' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    [...]

    {{ form.filename.errors }}
    {% render_field form.filename type="text" class+="form-control" id="plsFilename" placeholder=form.filename.label %}
```